# Starting with Qt Designer and PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I love Python and I have heard a lot about Qt, so lately I've started creating simple GUI applications.
When I convert by pyuic *.ui file to *.py everything looks familiar, understandable and reasonable. Except for one moment.

```
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)
```

and then a lot of lines like:

```
MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))

MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Surname", None))
```

When I create any application without using **_fromUtf8()** and **_translate()** methods like:

```
MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
self.label_5.setText("Surname")
```

everything works as well.

So, here is a question:
Do I really need to use **_fromUtf8()** and **_translate()** methods?

If yes, why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've similarly just started off using PySide and the output from the ui -> py files are similar, although it has `QApplication.translate(string, string, None, unicodeUTF8)`. I'm assuming this is because QT has an inbuilt translation utility. It's probably a good idea if you're planning on porting to multiple countries. But if you're doing something like me, where all strings are based off of user input, it's probably unnecessary.

Comment: No. The leading underscores indicate they are internal functions used only within the module auto-generated by pyuic. You should never use them within your own code (and you should also never edit the module auto-generated by pyuic). The functions are used for [i18n](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html), but if you want to implement that in your own code you should use the [tr and trUtf8](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#tr) methods. The i18n features are completely optional though, so they can be safely omitted if you're sure you won't need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are utilized for [internationalization](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html) of your application. If you are not planning on ever supporting the UI in multiple languages, then you can disable all of the `translatable` settings on your Widget.

Several Widgets have multiple areas that have this setting. For example, a `QLabel` has 4:

- toolTip
- statusTip
- whatsThis
- text

The `_fromUtf8` is utilized if you are using a language that utilizes characters that occupy more than ASCII characters (think anything with diacritics or multi-byte characters).